# SQL Server Concurrent User Limit 1 - Locked Out

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, ssms, limit

Accidentally set concurrent user limit to 1 and I locked myself out. I can't go back into properties to change. I've tried running this script but since i'm not connected I can't execute:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO  

EXEC sp_configure 'user connections', 325 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

What can I do?

Comment: It sounds like you will need to kill all the database connections (possibly by stopping the instance and restarting it) and make sure you are the one to connect.

Comment: You should always be able to get a [DAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/remote-admin-connections-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Restart the SQLServer Service, and login as the DAC first:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#connecting-with-dac

Then run your script.